# Динамическая память (Pascal)

Tags: pascal

По сути дела, создаю список, заполняю его какими то числами, и потом хочу удалить элемент  с ключом `= 6`, но не получается, даже после `dispose(b)` он умудряется мне без проблем выводить результат 6, как это? Мозг не может вьехать, я же поидеи удалил из памяти ячейку с номером b, ну или как то так

```
type
  stack = ^st;
  st = record
      data:Integer;
      next:stack;
  end;
var
    i,k:Integer;
  b,a,c:stack;
begin
    new(b);
    b^.data:=0;
    a:=b;
    for i := 1 to 9 do
    begin
        new(b^.next);
        b:=b^.next;
        b^.data:=i;
    end;
    k:=6;
    c:=a;
    while c<>nil do
    begin
        if c^.data = k then
        begin
          b:=c;
          c:=c^.next;
          break;
        end;
        c:=c^.next;
    end;
    dispose(b);
    WriteLn(b^.data);
      {
    while a<>nil do
    begin
        WriteLn(a^.data);
        a:=a^.next;
    end;              }
    ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Некорректно удаляется элемент из списка. Для удаления нужно изменить поле next элемента, предшествующего удаляемому на поле next удаляемого элемента. А здесь просто указатель на текущий элемент (никак не связанный с предыдущим элементом) меняется на указатель на следующий элемент.

P.S. я вижу сравнение c с nil, но не вижу чтобы в next какого-то из элементов nil записывался.

Comment: спасибо действительно я не правильно сделал вот исправления

    while c<>nil do

    begin

        if c^.data = k then break;

        b:=c;{предыдущий элемент}

        c:=c^.next;{элемент со значением k}

    end;

    b^.next:=c^.next;{перевожу указатель next предыдущего на указатель next найденного}

    dispose(c);{освобождаю память}

Answer (score 0):

```
while c<>nil do
begin
    if c^.data = k then break;
    b:=c;{предыдущий элемент}
    c:=c^.next;{элемент со значением k}
end;
b^.next:=c^.next;{перевожу указатель next предыдущего на указатель next найденного}
dispose(c);{освобождаю память}
```

Comment: Да, вроде правильно. По поводу nil, после цикла инициализации нужно вставить `b^.next:=nil;`